# RSS news feed to Java Application

Tags: java, rss

I am trying to add a sidebar to a Java application that will have a news feed from a website, most likely computerweekly.com, and will display the most recent stories with a link from the title to the online article.

I am pretty sure I need to somehow use an RSS feed, at least that's what seems to me would be the easiest way. But I'm exactly sure how I would do this.

Let's say I wanted the articles from this RSS feed: http://www.computerweekly.com/rss/All-Computer-Weekly-content.xml to show up on the side panel of a project, could someone tell me how I would get started in doing so?

If I didn't explain that well enough, I'd be happy to try again, thanks all!

Comment: What have you already researched?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RSSFeed/article.html I tried to follow along with this guy's code but after working through it and understanding it, no matter what feed I tried using, I got an UnknownHostException error

Comment: As well as just researching, searching youtube, etc, I just haven't been able to find much about cleanly adding it into a Java application, maybe my search-fu is just week though

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from a year ago but if your still working on this I would recommend:
http://rometools.github.io/rome/

I hope this helps.